# execute a function before all form.submit();

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, submit

There is any way to prevent all form submissions?

My idea is for instance, I have a Link with onclick="form.submit();" or a input[type=submit], etc, and I need before all submissions execute a function

Real Example:
I've that link:

```
 <a style="margin-right: 2px; margin-left: 2px;" target="_self" href="#" onclick="if(validateform(form)) form.submit(); return false;"><img border="0" title="Insert" src="/images/ico_save_changes.png"></a>
```

I've try:

```
jQuery(form).on("submit", function(event)){ event.preventDefault(); alert("ON"); return false;}) 
jQuery(form).live("submit", function(event)){ event.preventDefault(); alert("LIVE"); return false;}) 
jQuery(form).submit( function(event)){ event.preventDefault(); alert("EVENT"); return false;})
```

Without success... 
The form is always submitted and my alerts are not displayed...

Someone can help me?

Comment: where is your `validateform` function?

Comment: The submit handler is only run when form submission is triggered by the user, not when it's done from Javascript code.

Comment: @barmar so since I'm doing form.submit(); there is no way to prevent the default event, Am I right?

Comment: Right. Default only comes into play when the user clicks something, not when you force it from code.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function in jQuery, and Call it onclick, or whereever you want to call, then at the end of the function you can call another function if you want to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an event handler to catch form submission from Javascript. The submit event is only triggered when the user submits the form.

You'll need to put what you want into a function, and then call that from the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Change so that validation form is called when the image is clicked and submits form if validated ok.

```js
function validateForm() {
    //get your form information
  
    if (EVERYTHING OK) {
        //Returning true will submit the form
        $('#form1').submit();
    }else{
        alert("Form validation failed");
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="#" method="post" id="form1">
Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1">
</form>

<img border="0" title="Insert" src="/images/ico_save_changes.png" onclick="validateForm()">
```

Comment: Ok, I've changed the code so that the function is called when the image is clicked and if the validation is ok it submits the form